# Contar resultado de uma variavel

Tags: php

Colegas. Não sei se fui claro no meu título, mas vou tentar explicar aqui. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
    foreach($notasAlunos as $notaAluno){                                   
    $resXML = $xml->avaliacao->disciplina->questao->resposta;
    if($resXML == $notaAluno){
        $valor = 1; 
        echo count($valor);
    }else{
        $valor = 0;
    }
    //echo $valor;
  }
```

Preciso somar a quantidade de "1" que a variável $valor nos traz. Tentei usar o count($valor), mas está trazendo "111". Como eu faria para somar esses valores e retornar 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize Assim:

```
    foreach($notasAlunos as $notaAluno){                                   
       $resXML = $xml->avaliacao->disciplina->questao->resposta;
       if($resXML == $notaAluno){
           $valor++;           
       }else{
           $valor = 0;
        }

    }
    echo $valor;
```

No seu código você está sempre setando a variavel `$valor` com 1;

No meu código estou sempre incrementando + 1;

Comment: Olá tiago. Fiz dessa forma, mas ele retorna agora 1 2 e não apenas 2

Comment: Alterei o código, coloque o `echo` fora do `foreach`

Comment: Ele agora não retorna valor

Comment: Troca o lugar do echo $valor, coloca entre as duas ultimas chaves

Comment: Olá diego, mas colocar aonde exatamente? dentro do laço?

Comment: Tem que ser fora do laço

Comment: Oi Tiago. Fiz da forma como mencionou, mas infelizmente não retorna valores. Fica null.

Comment: Tem que iniciar a variavel com zero `$valor = 0` antes de incrementar.

Comment: Iniciei e também nada...

Comment: @Jose.Marcos iniciar fora do `for`, veja um exemplo: https://ideone.com/7rKta6

Comment: Pode ser que ele não esteja entrando no laço

Comment: @Jose.Marcos inicie `$valor = 0` fora do `for`, remova o else interno do if. Assim, mesmo que não entre, o resultado será zero.

Comment: Utilizando a ferramenta que o @DiegoF recomendou http://ideone.com/hcLO6I este exemplo funciona.

Comment: TiagoS tem certeza que funciona? `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: valor in /home/1IA14d/prog.php on line 4`

Comment: tenho, por favor olhe no stdout o resultado.

Comment: Veja o erro que retorna.